# Modifying OpenLDAP ldif file throwing an error, but successfully configure?

Tags: openldap, fedora

I was configuring OpenLDAP on my Fedora 17. When doing this `slaptest`, I got this output:

```
50f16531 hdb_db_open: warning - no DB_CONFIG file found in directory /var/lib/ldap: (2).
Expect poor performance for suffix "dc=my-domain,dc=com".
config file testing succeeded
```

I fixed that problem by modifying that string into my own domain name locate at `slapd.d/cn=config/olcDatabase={2}hdb.ldif`. When I do this `slaptest` again, I got this output:

```
50f16987 ldif_read_file: checksum error on "/etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config/olcDatabase={2}hdb.ldif"
50f16987 hdb_db_open: warning - no DB_CONFIG file found in directory /var/lib/ldap: (2).
Expect poor performance for suffix "dc=huahsin,dc=org".
config file testing succeeded
```

May I know does this mean the test has been successfully being configured?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been successfully configured, there's just no [DB_CONFIG](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17076_02/html/api_reference/C/configuration_reference.html) file. You probably have a `DB_CONFIG.example` file somewhere that you forgot to copy into `/var/lib/ldap/DB_CONFIG`, set the correct permissions on, and edit to suit your configuration.